# Can bash wildcards specify negative matches?

Tags: bash, wildcards

In `bash` is it possible to use wildcards to specify "all files in current directory EXCEPT [files matching a specific (wildcard) pattern]"? Eg, "all files which don't match *~"

Or more generally, is it possible to qualify a wildcard file-spec with a second, filtering or negating specification?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course. Let's say you want all files the contain the string "foo" in their name, but none who also contain "bar". So you want

```
foo1
foo2
```

But you don't want

```
 foobar1
```

You can use simple globbing to do that like so:

```
for f in foo!(bar)*; echo $f; done
```

or so

```
ls foo[^bar]*
```

For more see here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html Beware, both methods have their pitfalls. You are probably better off using `find`.

Comment: Ah, I see - part of the `extglob shopt`. I don't usually have it enabled.

Comment: Note `[^bar]` does match a single character, all excluding b, a, and r.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks bjanssen for pointing out bash's `extglob shopt` which allows this kind of globbing.

From the `bash` manpage:

```
If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several
extended pattern matching operators are recognized. In the following 
description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated 
by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the following
sub-patterns:

          ?(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
          *(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
          +(pattern-list)
                 Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
          @(pattern-list)
                 Matches one of the given patterns
          !(pattern-list)
                 Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

So, to answer my question "how to specify *all files which don't match *~*" :

```
!(*~)
```

or, without the need for `extglob`:

```
*[^~]
```

And more generally, answering the last part of my question:

```
The GLOBIGNORE shell variable may be used to restrict the set of file names
matching a pattern. If GLOBIGNORE is set, each matching file name that also
matches one of the (colon-separated) patterns in GLOBIGNORE is removed from
the list of matches.
```

Comment: *[^~] worked for me